Do Password Filter DLLs need to be Signed?
Background:
I have spent a little over a month working on a simple Password Filter DLL that just passes any changed passwords out to PowerShell so it can take care of updating other systems that need to know about the change. It's not working, and I think I've figured out why, but rather than just assuming I'm right I figured that I would post a question here. That way I could either get confirmation of my suspicions, or guidance on what to do next. Either way, at the very least, someone else might find this one day and it might help them decide whether or not to tackle creating their own Password Filter DLL.
Question:
As of May, 2024, in a Server 2016+ Domain Controller, does a Password Filter DLL need to be signed by Microsoft with an EV code signing certificate, the same way drivers do?
Additional Information:
As I said, I have spent quite a bit of time working on making my own Password Filter DLL, which is intended to be used in-house. So when I finally got all of the bugs worked out (I hope), and it still wasn't working, I went back to Google to try and figure out why. Unfortunately, there is a lot of conflicting and outdated information out there.
So, let me tell you what I've done and what I'm seeing.

I'm working on a new Windows Server 2016 VM
I wrote the DLL in C++, using Visual Studio 2022
At one point in time, I had enabled LSA protection (setting RunAsPPL to 1), but then I found out that that would actually cause me problems, and was able to turn it off.
The DLL is in the Windows\System32 folder and has been added to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Lsa/Notification Packages.
I have tried both unsigned and self-signed versions.

When I reboot the server, in the Event viewer I find these entries.
Under Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > CodeIntegrity > Operational,

Event ID: 3066
Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\lsass.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\SD60PWS.dll that did not meet the Microsoft signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy. However, due to code integrity auditing policy, the image was allowed to load.

Under Security,

Event ID: 5038, 5/3/2024 7:37:10 AM
Code integrity determined that the image hash of a file is not valid.  The file could be corrupt due to unauthorized modification or the invalid hash could indicate a potential disk device error.
File Name:    \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\SD60PWS.dll

The first message makes it look like the DLL was loaded, but the second message makes it look like it has been blocked.
The three DLLs currently listed in Notification Packages are rassfm, scecli, and SD60PWS. I found a PowerShell command to check to see if they have been loaded by lsass.exe, and here's what I get from those commands:
PS C:\Windows\system32> tasklist /m rass*

Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
lsass.exe                      596 rassfm.DLL
PS C:\Windows\system32> tasklist /m scec*

Image Name                     PID Modules
========================= ======== ============================================
lsass.exe                      596 scecli.DLL
PS C:\Windows\system32> tasklist /m sd60*
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
PS C:\Windows\system32>


(BTW, if you want to just see all of the files loaded by lsass.exe, the command is tasklist /m /FI "IMAGENAME eq lsass.exe")
OK, so the DLL isn't loading, but why? The message that comes with the 5038 Event is a little confusing. I mean why would the image hash of the file not be valid, it's a brand new file? Also, the file hasn't had any unauthorized modification, and I'm pretty sure there's no potential disk device errors in the virtual HDD.
A lot of what I found on the internet regarding this Event ID: 5038 was geared towards, "Monitor for this event, because it could mean that you have a virus or a HDD issue." However, I eventually found this page from Microsoft which reads:

Code Integrity detects whether an unsigned driver or system file is being loaded into the kernel, or whether a system file has been modified...

When I saw that I thought, "Well, that explains the error I'm getting." I was pretty sure that 'unsigned driver' really means 'not signed my Microsoft' and that all of my attempts at self-signing were for not.
Coming to this conclusion was a little disheartening for me, because a lot of what I found prior to starting this project (including Microsoft's own pages {1,2,3}) just said, "Make a DLL, put it in this folder, add it to this key, reboot, and Bob's your uncle!" Looking back at a lot of the pages I'd looked at before, I see that a lot of them are more than two or three years old and a lot can change in that time. I mean, I get it, the 'simple' solution I thought I found would also be really easy for a hacker to set up and capture any changed passwords, so I can see why Microsoft might have made it so that Password Filter DLLS need to be properly code signed. I just wish I knew that going in.
So, there you have it. I am reaching out to the stackoverflow community to either confirm my suspicions, or get some guidance on what to do next. At the very least, maybe having all of this information together will help someone else in the future.
Thank you.
Update:
We recently purchased an IdenTrust code signing cert (which was quite the process) and once I got my DLL signed it still wouldn't load. It gave me the exact same errors.
Now, here's the part that makes me think that Windows is expecting a DLL that's verified by Microsoft, the way drivers are. There are a couple of ways that you can sign a file, and the one that worked for me (eventually) was Sign Tool. Sign Tool has a way to verify that a file is signed, but when I checked my DLL, here's what I got...
SignTool verify SD60PWS.dll
File: SD60PWS.dll
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Number of errors: 1

When I looked up that error, I found that by default Sign Tool uses the Windows Driver Verification Policy. I needed to add the /pa switch to get it to use the the Default Authenticode Verification Policy.
SignTool verify /pa SD60PWS.dll

File: SD60PWS.dll
Index  Algorithm  Timestamp
========================================
0      sha256     RFC3161

Successfully verified: SD60PWS.dll

So, there you have it. If Sign Tool defaults to treating all files as drivers, doesn't it stand to reason that a system-level loaded DLL would also be treated as a driver? Maybe I'm way off here, but unless someone has more information, that is all I have to go on.
I tried to find information about how to get a Password Filter DLL signed, and I couldn't find anything. So I have abandoned the idea of writing our own DLL. Instead we are going to have to go with a third-party solution.
I hope this post helps inform someone else who is thinking about writing their own Password Filter DLL and lets them know that it's not as easy as Microsoft's documentation makes it seem.
Thank you

Addendum:
Just to make sure that adding and removing additional LSA security didn't mess up the VM, I spun up a brand new VM and tried the filter there... It did the same thing.
However, I also had to copy over 3 additional DLLs (and the PowerShell script) and that made me wonder about something. When Windows checks a Password Filter DLL, does it only check the DLL, or all of the files associated with it?
In other words, could my problem actually be with one of the additional DLLs or the PS script, and not my Password Filter DLL?
Thanks
